# How to use this site if an answer doesn't quite work?

Tags: discussion

I found a question with an answer that almost works, but I found an issue with it that it seems others haven't. I wanted to comment with the problem I've found and see if anyone had a solution, but it says you need 50 points to comment. I could make a new question, but my question is really the same as the existing question... I just have a problem with one of its answers. What are you supposed to do?

Comment: It's worth noting that if it generates a error because of a bad variable name or something like that; expect DVs on the new question. Make sure its an actual issue with the answer and not just you copy/pasting it and expecting code from the internet to "just work"

Comment: Could you [edit] here and say exactly what's wrong with the solution? You might be missing some required steps that would result in your question being downvoted. Sort of, add to this question what your new question would be.

Answer (score 18):

You're more than welcome (and encouraged) to post a question based on the answer of a preexisting question **in a separate question**.  Be sure to provide context around why this answer doesn't "quite work", since "work" is still a highly subjective thing.

Answer (score 10):

> my question is really the same as the existing question

Not exactly. Your new question would be "Why does this approach not work?". Make sure to link the answer where you found it, give a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your code, and describe the issue that you have with it (post the error message, or describe whatever else happens and what you would have expected instead).

That's a separate question, different than the original one. You should post it as a new question.